# I have it going in a complete loop and don't know how to make it stop

Tags: java

My teacher asked us to create a magic 8 ball program in Java 8. We have to use 3 methods, a main, a processing, and an output and we need to pass parameters between the methods. The output needs to use the `switch` statement, we need to have a `while` statement in there and the answers need to be randomly generated.  I have everything required but when I try to run the program it is stuck in the while loop and I don't know what I did wrong.
Here is what I have:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Magic8Ball {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Would you like to ask a question? Y or N: ");
        char answer = input.next().charAt(0);
        char Y = Character.toUpperCase(answer);
        process(answer, Y);
    }
    public static void process(char a, char Yes) {
        if (a != Yes) {
            System.out.println("Thank you, goodbye.");
        } else {
            while(a==Yes) {
                System.out.print("Ask your question: ");
                Random random = new Random();
                int ran = random.nextInt(8-1+1)+1;
                output(ran);
            }
        }
    }
    Public static int output(int r) {
        switch (r) {
        case 1: System.out.println("Out of memory, try again later); break;
        case 2: System.out.println("The probability matrix supports you."); break;
        case 3: System.out.println("That does not compute."); break;
        case 4: System.out.println("System error, try again later"); break;
        case 5: System.out.println("Siri says yes."); break;
        case 6: System.out.println("The asnwer could not be found on the internet."); break;
        case 7: System.out.println("Wikilinks claims it is true."); break;
        case 8: System.out.println("Siri says no."); break;
        default: System.out.println("The system is not responding, try again later"); break;
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't update neither `a` nor `Yes` in the loop.

Comment: you have to update the value of `a`  inside the loop when you want to quit...otherwise it will be an infinite loop

Comment: The condition is `while (a==Yes)` and you never change either `a` or `Yes`. (By the way, I am not sure why you do this test to begin with. It checks if the input is equal to the capital version of the input.)

Comment: You need to read the input inside the loop.

Comment: I kinda started an answer, but your code is full of bugs and logic flaws. Please think of the logic again, step by step. write it down in english words what happens when and what the comparisants are. You'll learn more fromt that. Put your while loop at the readline. not in the method.

Comment: @Lisa S If you do accept the answers for your previous post, you may get better response for your future questions.

Comment: I've added an answer, let me know if it fixes the problem ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Magic8Ball {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        System.out.print("Would you like to ask a question? Y or N: ");
        Scanner infeedScanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
        char input = infeedScanner.next().charAt(0);
        process(input, 'Y');
    }

    public static void process(char a, char Yes) 
    {
       if (a != Yes) 
       {
         System.out.println("Thank you, goodbye.");
       }
       else 
       {
           boolean bContinue = true;

           while(bContinue) 
           {
               System.out.print("Ask your question: ");
               Random random = new Random();
               int ran = random.nextInt(8-1+1)+1;
               output(ran);

               System.out.print("Would you like to ask another question? Y or N: ");
               Scanner infeedScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

               if (infeedScanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
               {
                   bContinue = false;
               }
           }
       }
    }

    public static int output(int r) 
    {     
        switch (r) {
            case 1: System.out.println("Out of memory, try again later"); break;
            case 2: System.out.println("The probability matrix supports you."); break;
            case 3: System.out.println("That does not compute."); break;
            case 4: System.out.println("System error, try again later"); break;
            case 5: System.out.println("Siri says yes."); break;
            case 6: System.out.println("The answer could not be found on the internet."); break;
            case 7: System.out.println("Wikilinks claims it is true."); break;
            case 8: System.out.println("Siri says no."); break;
            default: System.out.println("The system is not responding, try again later"); break;
        }

        return r;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all. There are a lot of typo in your code for example you have to close the " at the end of the first print statement in your method `output()`. Second error, Java is case sensitive so `Public` is not the same as `public`

Now, lets try to give you a simple solution for this problem simple solution could be this: add a return at the end of the while loop as you can see in the following code.

```
while(a == Yes) {
   System.out.print("Ask your question: ");
   Random random = new Random();
   int ran = random.nextInt(8-1+1)+1;
   output(ran);
   return;
}
```

In this way you stop looping after you print the first output.

Remember, `return` is a "magic world" you can use to say to your method to stop and come back with a result (in this case you have no result because the method returns a void).

It works for me, let me know if this is the right solution for your problem ;-)

Comment: Why would you use a return and while loop??? it makes more sense to have a correct boolean statement. In this case it only runs once and returns. So what is the use for the while statement????

Comment: Yea, you are right but I'm trying to leave the structure as is, without modify the code to much. I've seen in another post by Lisa S that the teacher remove point if he/she uses a different approach.

Comment: And that is a good thing that he deducts points. You should learn it correct and not incorrect.

Comment: No, the teacher deducts (thank you for this world ;-)) if shee modifies the structure of the code. For example in another question she had to use just for loops and not while. So a better solution based on a while wouldn't be a good solution.